# Angular $templatecache not working when i tried to include the cached template in html

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to cache `$templatecache` as my html is coming from controller as string than I just put it in to cache using `$templatecache` but when i am trying to include it in HTML using following statement than its showing me  404 not found error in console.

http://local.mydomain.com/myaccount/dqs.html 404 (Not found)

```
  "<div id="dqs" ng-include="'dqs.html'"  class="form__main" set-height></div>"
```

Angular code :

```
 $templateCache.put('dqs.html', filteredFormHtml);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are adding your template in html, you need to first cache that template by using **$templateRequest** service.

```
$templateRequest('/myaccount/dqs.html').then(function (filteredFormHtml) {
      $templateCache.put('filteredFormHtml', filteredFormHtml);
});
```

Once the template is cached, you can use it anywhere in your template using ng-include

```
"<div id="dqs" ng-include="'dqs.html'"  class="form__main" set-height></div>"
```

Below are the user links for better understanding on **$tempalteCache** Service

1) https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$templateCache

2) https://thinkster.io/templatecache-tutorial

Comment: Thanks its really works actually my html has loaded first and template was caching later.